Clarify the [cryptoapi] tag
My impression is that the cryptoapi tag is supposed to be about the subset of Windows API that deals with crypto (NCrypt, BCrypt, CAPICOM, CertEnroll and the like), and not about any API/library that provides crypto primitives (and certainly not about cryptocurrency).
If this is correct, maybe that should be made clear in the top line of the tag description.

The description I'm seeing is: "Cryptography API: Application programming interface that enables application developers to add authentication, encoding, and encryption to Windows-based applications. The API are oriented on the developer of unmanaged (native) applications in C/C++. " Is that not sufficiently clear already? If people are misusing the tag, maybe the name is the problem.

The first part of that description is plagiarized from Microsoft's glossary, it seems.

@KarlKnechtel It could certainly be clearer (although it rules out some of the more obviously wrong ones).  e.g., does it include Cryptography API: Next Generation (CNG)? Is CAPICOM part of CryptoAPI, or its own separate thing (as suggested by phrasing like "CryptoAPI, CAPICOM, and Certificate Services tasks")?

It needs usage guidance.  All that said, yes, the name is also confusing (see, e.g., the 25 questions tagged with [cryptoapi] and [cryptocurrency]). It should probably also be changed.

Retag wrong questions, then rename it to windows-cryptoapi or maybe even adding the main programming language too into the tag, I assume C#? -> windows-c#-cryptoapi to make it entirely clear what it's about

Arguably, this tag should be disambiguated or burninated, it's too ambiguous to be useful. By grouping all cryptography APIs for Windows together, it's not more useful than just [tag:windows] + [tag:cryptography]. CNG/CAPICOM/CertEnroll are not very related. @Lino since it's a wide variety of APIs either used through COM or a native interface, these can be used in most programming languages for Windows.

@ErikA That sounds like it may be a solution worth further discussion; consider posting it as an answer.

Generally the first sentence should be a short summary, for people who don't click-thru to check out the details of the correct usage; and so it shows up in the brief description. As for the remainder it should describe the early usage and might be improved by aligning with other site's usage.

There are two paragraphs in the tag description. The first paragraph correctly describes what I remember as the Windows crypto api, a very old API. The second paragraph seems gratuitous, unhelpful, and ultimately misleading.

This tag seems to have initiated around the old, deprecated Windows Cryptoapi (the stuff declared in Wincrypt.h). It thus appears to be synonymous with wincrypt.
The best course forward would likely be to disambiguate the tag, add a new tag description, and possibly merge it with wincrypt

Proposed tag rename and wiki:
We can merge the tag with wincrypt after disambiguation and use the name of that tag to avoid confusion.
Wiki:
Windows Crypto API, declared in wincrypt.h, is a deprecated native API to work with encryption, authentication and certificates in Windows. It can leverage cryptography service providers to allow hardware-accelerated cryptography. This tag is not to be used for different cryptography APIs, or cryptocurrency.

Alternate tags:

General questions about cryptography can be retagged cryptography, possibly with windows if they are about a Windows-specific implementation.
Anything regarding CAPICOM, the COM inteface to the old Windows cryptography API, can be retagged capicom.
Anything regarding the replacement of Crypto API, Cryptography API: Next Generation (CNG), can be retagged cng.
Anything regarding cryptocurrency and APIs can be tagged with cryptocurrency, and tagged with the appropriate coin and/or API if/when this tag exists.

Likely, the majority of recent questions should be retagged, since this API is not recommended for new development.
